# oracle sql compare two columns and if match update id_value loop

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm kind new on Oracle SQL and i'm lost on who to compare two colums from two different tables; like last_name and first_name from table A and table B, and if both colums vlaues match on both tables then update value_id from table B to table A.

Comment: This question is just like saying, *my car doesn't go, how to make it go*. What about posting a test case?

Comment: I tried to enter the case but it was kind of confusing using the code method. next time will include it. thanks for your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done with a `MERGE` statement.
Lets build some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (VALUE_ID INTEGER, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15));
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (VALUE_ID INTEGER, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(15), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15));
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (1, 'SMITH', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (2, 'ADAMS', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (3, 'ADAMS', 'SAM');
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (4, 'BOOTH', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (5, 'HENRY', 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (VALUE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
VALUES (6, 'ADAMS', 'SAM');
```

Now whats in there:

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

  VALUE_ID LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 SMITH           JOHN
         2 ADAMS           JOHN
         3 ADAMS           SAM

SQL> select * from table_b;

  VALUE_ID LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         4 BOOTH           JOHN
         5 HENRY           JOHN
         6 ADAMS           SAM

SQL>
```

Now lets [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) them together:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A A
USING (
  SELECT B.VALUE_ID, B.FIRST_NAME, B.LAST_NAME
  FROM TABLE_B b) b
ON (B.FIRST_NAME = A.FIRST_NAME AND B.LAST_NAME = A.LAST_NAME) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET VALUE_ID=b.VALUE_ID
;
```

Now whats in there?

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

  VALUE_ID LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 SMITH           JOHN
         2 ADAMS           JOHN
         6 ADAMS           SAM

SQL> select * from table_b;

  VALUE_ID LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME
---------- --------------- ---------------
         4 BOOTH           JOHN
         5 HENRY           JOHN
         6 ADAMS           SAM

SQL>
```

So we've `MERGE` `VALUE_ID` into `TABLE_A` where `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` are found in both tables.

Comment: I appreciate your respond. It does make sense using merge. I have not tried but i know that will work.